# How to customize slides in landscape class?

Tags: landscape, presentations

I'd like to use landscape class/slides in order to make presentations, but I need to customize it in order:

1. to have an outline
2. to set a navigation bar
3. to insert pictures

Do you think it's possible? This is a MWE, found here https://texblog.org/2008/01/21/create-your-slides-presentations-with-latex/:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}
\textcolor{blue}{\Large{Distance}\footnote{Source: Wolfram MathWorld}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{The distance between two points is the length of the path connecting them.}
\item In the plane, the distance between points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is given by the Pythagorean theorem,
$$d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$
\end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\begin{slide} \textcolor{blue}{\Large{Distance con't}}
\begin{itemize}
\item In Euclidean three-space, the distance between points $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ is
$$d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$$
\item In general, the distance between points \textbf{x} and \textbf{y} and  in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by
$$d=|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}|=\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}{|x_i-y_i|^2}}$$
\end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define aspect ratio for the beamer's slides, however it don't know for `landscape` orientation.

Comment: Don't use `slides` for presentations. The class isn't designed for this. It's designed for things like making overhead transparencies of something you'd show with a document viewer, as opposed to a projector.

Comment: Most people use beamer class for presentations, but you can also use the pdfscreen package.